# Pip not installing correctly

Tags: python, pip

I am operating on a Mac and using Enthought python  I have installed PIP but am having difficulty installing packages.

When I attempt to install Pygame, the package is downloading and begins building but then errors.  I realize that Pygame is a relatively complex package but I have similar same problem with simpler packages.  Because I thought it may have to do with my installation of Python, I show my env variables at the end.  Any help would be appreciated

the trace looks like:

```
running build_ext

building 'pygame._numericsurfarray' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/src

gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch i386 -I/NEED_INC_PATH_FIX -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/include/python2.7 -c src/_numericsurfarray.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/src/_numericsurfarray.o

In file included from src/_numericsurfarray.c:23:

src/pygame.h:106:17: error: SDL.h: No such file or directory

In file included from src/_numericsurfarray.c:23:

src/pygame.h:350: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘SDL_VideoInfo’

src/pygame.h:388: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘SDL_Surface’

src/_numericsurfarray.c:26:27: error: SDL_byteorder.h: No such file or directory
....
....
...
....
src/_numericsurfarray.c:1097: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SDL_Surface’

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

---

```
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/folders/9m/qcp8h8ss4ng1v8429jvnkkrc0000gn/T/pip-build/pygame/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/9m/qcp8h8ss4ng1v8429jvnkkrc0000gn/T/pip-roxs9O-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/9m/qcp8h8ss4ng1v8429jvnkkrc0000gn/T/pip-build/pygame
Storing complete log in /Users/jc_macpro/.pip/pip.log
```

my environment variables are:

```
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
TMPDIR=/var/folders/9m/qcp8h8ss4ng1v8429jvnkkrc0000gn/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-iwuiuZ/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=309
TERM_SESSION_ID=FDC661E1-1196-448F-8D69-28AD9D7C496B
USER=jc_macpro
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-pH83z9/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
Apple_Ubiquity_Message=/tmp/launch-s4tuBY/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
PWD=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/jc_macpro
LOGNAME=jc_macpro
SECURITYSESSIONID=186a4
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin
```

I would appreciate any help.

UPDATE: 12/22/12
I have sifted through al of the advice and feedback and appreciate it all very much.  All efforts at installing the binaries on Enthought did not work.  I did not want o add more complexity with Macports so I decided to blow out my Enthought python and simply work with the official Python 2.7.  I am a huge fan of Enthought and it was a great way to provide a stable base from which to work when I started messing around with Python.  However, as was pointed out it has some limitations.

With Python 2.7 as my default I reinstalled pip, added basic functionality and was then able to install the binaries necessary for pygame, numpy, matplotlib, and wxPython.  So now I functioning and once again dangerous - just now with official Python 2.7!!  Thank you all.

Comment: As a side note: I haven't used Enthought in a while, but `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/` looks wrong. That ought to be `2.7` or `2.7.3`, not `7.3`, unless this is some weird thing they've deliberately done to avoid colliding with Python.org 2.7.3 or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need SDL to install PyGame. You may also want to install various SDL add-on packages (SDL_ttf for fonts, etc.) as well.

As Martijn Pieters suggests, Pygame comes with a binary installer for Mac. I have no idea whether it will work with Enthought Python, but I'd try that first.

If it fails, SDL also has a [binary installer](https://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php) for Mac. Again, I don't know if it will work for you, but I'd try it next.

If that fails, I'd use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Homebrew (unlike MacPorts and Fink) is designed to work well with any Python installation you want to use, and with that Python's `pip`. (See [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew) and [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew) for details.) So, type `brew search sdl` to get a list of all of the add-on packages, and then `brew install sdl sdl_foo sdl_bar etc.` to install them.

For your additional problem, that you can't `pip install` *anything* because of permissions errors in '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`, that's an easy one: You don't have permission to write to that directory. There are two ways to fix it:

1. Use `sudo pip install foo` instead of `pip install foo`.
2. Use `sudo chmod -R a+w /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` to give yourself write access, so you can `pip install foo`. (You may need to add a few other directories.)

The second one is very much in the spirit of Homebrew (see the two links above, which go into more detail on how and why to do this), and it works great with python.org packages because many people are using it that way regularly, but I can't guarantee that it's a good idea with Enthought packages, while I *can* guarantee the first one.

Comment: OK.  First things, first.  Thank You.  The sudo pip install yolk worked perfectly.  As for pygame, on my desktop mac i installed pip and then pip installed pygame flawlessly.  all with 32 bit Enthought so something is weird.  I use Enthought simply because I am a noob and direct compiling scares the heck out of me.  Sounds like I have to get over it and dive in.  I'll read about homebrew.  in the meantime, I'll try as you suggest on pygame.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @NewatPython: On your desktop Mac, you must have already had SDL somehow. The pygame installer is supposed to bail out earlier than it did when it fails to find SDL, but it isn't supposed to _work_, because there's no way it could. (If you can remember what you did on the desktop, presumably the same thing will work here, but I'm guessing you can't.)

Comment: @NewatPython: Meanwhile, there's nothing wrong with using Enthought. numpy/scipy can be a pain to install yourself, even with Homebrew, especially if you want the full Fortran stuff. But it doesn't include everything in the world; you'll still occasionally need to learn to find and install prerequisites for other things, like `SDL` for `pygame`, or `libxml2` for `lxml`, etc., whether you do it through binaries, through Homebrew, or through manual compilation.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a dependency, SDL.

If you have macports install, use that to install `libsdl`.

Or better still, download the [Pygame binary for Mac](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml); it includes the SDL library in the installer.

Comment: I would not use MacPorts to install SDL, unless you also want to use MacPorts Python. If you're using Enthought, Apple, or python.org Python, it's usually much better to find a binary, use Homebrew, or build manually.

Comment: @abarnert: best would be to use the Pygame installer in this case. No idea what the OP is using or why they wanted to use `pip` though.

Comment: Yes, as long as that works with Enthought Python. Having not checked that, I don't know if it will work.

Comment: @Martijn To be fair, having a single package manager to install everything is much nicer than having to look for binary files all over the internet. If there is a pip package I'd generally try that one first too.

Comment: @Voo: But there's not going to be a pip package for SDL, because it's not a Python library. Homebrew, unlike MacPorts, is designed to work well with any Python installation you want, and its `pip`, but it's not prefect.

Comment: Just one clarification though.  I think I may have multiple issues. Pip is not installing anything.  When I try and install yolk, i get th e following:creating /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yolk

error: could not create '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yolk': Permission denied

Comment: @NewatPython: If you have two separate problems, you should create two separate questions. But I think I can guess the problem there: You're missing a `sudo`

Comment: @NewatPython: That's a different problem, use `sudo pip` to install in your Enthought python directories.

Comment: @abarnert: Note that a macports-installed SDL would be useable by Enthough Python, but there will be more dependencies, I fear.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It _may_ be usable, but it won't always work; I've had serious problems mixing MacPorts packages with non-MacPorts Python, and they're painful to debug, especially since the MacPorts community's answer is always "stop that, use our Python" (not to mention "don't use `pip`, install a `port` for it). Anyway, I still think the PyGame binary installer should be the first thing he tries. If it works with Enthought, he's done. And if it does, the OP can accept your answer, and that will be very useful to future readers. So +1, but I wish you'd remove the macports part.

Comment: As was pointed out, there were two problems here (although I didn't realize it at the time the question was written).  The minor issue was that I did not understand the sudo workaround to get "root" privileges.  That got pip working immediately.  The challenge of the pygame installation and sdl dependency, however, remained.